# Ribbon and DockManager practices

Tags: gui-design, wpf, ribbon

In our current application we have one window with a Ribbon at the top and actually 3 panels.
We can switch the panel by clicking on tabs (at the left).
The Ribbon content depend on the selected panel.

We wan't to introduice a DockManager to allow the user to undock the panel (in a new window).

We see two options:

- Have a Ribbon on top of each windows, but it's a loose of space.
- Kept only one Ribbon in the main window, and continue to update its content depending on the selected panel. But the synchronization between multiple windows seems weird.

What is the common behavior for a application that combine DockManager and Ribbon?
Have you any example of application that use both of them.

Comment: can you share any wireframes/screenshots of this?

Comment: I can't. It's a professional software.

Answer (score 2):

AutoCAD allows undocking of ribbons. It allows users to undock ribbons and use them as side panels. Refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nH9PV2Ag9t0).

If the video becomes unavailable:

- The right-click dropdown on the ribbon contains the "Undock" option.
- It undocks the whole ribbon and presents it as a draggable panel (The tab titles become left aligned)
- This panel is resizable and it can be "Anchored to right" and "Anchored to left" (just like in IDE or Adobe CC app).